# Reply to the Notification Post in sagepay (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, opayo

I am creating a inframe payment gateway for Sagepay. I have the first bit working fine, using wp_remote_post to send my request and getting back an ok with the next url and putting that in an iframe. My problem comes on handling the response. I always get it moving out of the iframe and onto the test.sage.com to process the payment and then a 5006 error code which is the 'Unable to redirect to Vendor's web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL.'. I understand that I need to give a similar response to how sagepay tells me it's cool with my response, something like:

```
Status=ok
RedirectURL=http://
```

But I am really confused how I convey this. I tried simply:

```
echo '
        Status=ok ' . PHP_EOL . '
        RedirectURL=https://url/sagepay/callbacks
    ';
```

but get the same error. The integration kits seem to give examples for everything minus the inframe method. But just really confused how I handle this.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you provide a plain text header..

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
```

and provide your response like this:

```
echo 'Status=OK' . chr(13) . chr(10) . 'RedirectURL=https://url/sagepay/callbacks' . chr(13) . chr(10);
```

This is how I send my response to SagePay.. it is important to not have any whitespace before and after your response..

Comment: yeah I have tried similar, and this also. It's moving outside of the iframe and goes to: https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/authorisation after the 3D-Secure scheme, is that normal?

Comment: yeh it is, the iframe part is purely for the initial transaction, giving the card details etc, it then breaks out of the iframe to finalize.. thats why i've moved to using direct integration for more control

Comment: Hi, sorry for bringing this back up after all this time but have come back to this and still a bit confused. Is this code on a page that you passed sagepay via 'NotificationURL'? So you'd just have a blank php file say with the above code?